# proving a inequality involving a definite integral

Tags: inequality

Consider
$$L = {2012}^{\frac13}+{2013}^{\frac13}+\cdots +{3011}^{\frac13}$$ 
$$R = {2013}^{\frac13}+{2014}^{\frac13}+\cdots +{3012}^{\frac13}$$ 
and $$I =\int\limits_{2012}^{3012} x^{\frac13} dx$$.
Then prove that $$L+R<2I$$

i tried to plot the graph of $x^{\frac13}$ but i couldnot get an idea on how to solve this.

please help me in this regard.thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plot the graph of $f(x):= x^{1/3}$ between $a$ and $b$. You'll see that the graph always lies *above* the straight line connecting the points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b, f(b))$. Therefore the area under $f$ from $a$ to $b$ exceeds the (trapezoid) area under that straight line, i.e.
$$
\int\limits_a^b f(x)dx> (b-a)\left(\frac{f(a) + f(b)}2\right)\tag1$$
Now apply (1) to
$$\int\limits_{2012}^{3012}f(x)\,dx =\sum_{t=2012}^{3011}\int\limits_t^{t+1}f(x)\,dx.$$
Aside: You can prove (1) rigorously by appealing to the fact that  $f$ is *strictly concave*.